# How to create interactive PDF allowing the user to fill in form fields

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe, activereports, grapecity

Hi i am having a strange requirement where Client wants the PDF to be User interactive(.i.e to have fillable form fields) like entering the name in text box inside pdf and several other fields. we usually work with Activereports 9 to generate reports. I have searched a lot its not possible with Activereports9 and i gone through iTextframe library and started working with it but no clue how to get required functionality.

I was sucessful to add the textbox to the pdf but co-ordinates to place the textbox on the pdf am facing trouble.

my code is like this,

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField oTextField = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(oPdfStamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(171, 195, 562, 404), "txtName");
```

Need asssitance guys,using any other tool or iTextFrame how i can achieve the functionality.

Comment: would they only save the PDF file after filling the textbox?  what is their expectation of the filled data?   We have considered such feature in the past.